# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException : No qualifying bean, Error in SpringBoot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have SpringBoot Application (MainApplication). On `ApplicationReadyEvent` I am trying to trigger the `Quartz event`, but my service class gets

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type error.
```

MainApplication.java

```java
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void doSomethingAfterStartup() {
    strtsch.startSchedular();
}
```

StartupScheduler

```java
@Component
public class StartupScheduler implements ApplicationListener<SpringApplicationEvent> {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    public void startSchedular() {
        SchedulerJobService jobService = (SchedulerJobService) context.getBean(SchedulerJobService.class);
        // error org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'SchedulerJobService' available
        // at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBean
    }
}
```

SchedulerJobService

```java
@Transactional
@Component
@Scope(value="singleton")
public class SchedulerJobService implements InitializingBean {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        context.getBean("SchedulerJobService");
        System.out.println("ScheduleJobService is up");
    }
}
```

Want to check where am i going wrong / what am i missing so that i can access my service bean which has method to load quartz schedule.

Above code runs fine when i run it from eclipse but, get above error when i created Runnable Jar from eclipse and run it from command prompt.

Thanks,

Comment: No qualifying bean of type what?

Answer (score 0):

Please, use either `@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)` and do not implement  `ApplicationEventListener` interface, or, more readable and logical, remove please `@EventListener` from `MainApplication` and make `StartupScheduler` implement `ApplicationEventListener<ApplicationReadyEvent>`. You have messed up a bit the events configuration. Make it clear, because now you have 2 event listeners in your app.

Addressing the question:

The context you've injected does not have a `SchedulerJobService` bean. Now, having that you have ***2 listeners in your app, and each of them operate on different stages of ApplicationContext construction***, there could be 2 possible issues.

1. You are trying to get bean from context on `ContextStartedEvent` for example (Which can be easily the case since your `StartupScheduler` listens for all `SpringApplicationEvent` events). When this event is fired, the ***spring just started the context construction***, it will not have `StartupScheduler` bean yet. So you will get this error. To check if it is the case, please provide the complete code of these 3 classes.
2. It could be, that the `StartupScheduler` bean is just out of `ComponentScan`, and spring does not even now that this bean exists. To verify that this is not, since I do not know you project packages structure, you can just annotate your MainApplication with `@Import(StartupScheduler)` (to not mess up you current `@ComponentScan`). This way the spring will bring  required bean into the context.

Comment: Hi Mihail, Thanks for responding. I feel it could be case 1. So is there any spring listener which will get fired after all spring beans are loaded and i can access the StartupScheduler.

Comment: I guess you mean events :) Yes, there are. For instance `ApplicationReadyEvent`. That one is fired after spring context is fully build. Please, approve the answer and upvote it if it works for you.

Comment: Hi Mihail,
Yes i am already using the @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class) to init the startup activity, but i am still getting error of no qualifying been even when been is @Component as mentioned in origin question.
Can you guide me to find what am i missing out here.
Note : its running fine in eclipse but getting above error when running it as Runnable Jar.
Thanks

Comment: @atul ahireYour `StartupScheduler` is also implements the `ApplicationListener` interface, and you do not show the entire code. As I said, please, show the entire classes code.